# Apache Camel: multicast with aggregation - AggregationStrategy called too often

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following strange (or at least unclear to me) behaviour for a multi-cast + aggregation. Consider the following route:

```
    from("direct:multicaster")
                .multicast()
                .to("direct:A", "direct:B")
                .aggregationStrategy(new AggregationStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                        if (oldExchange == null) {
                            List firstResult = newExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                            newExchange.getIn().setBody(ImmutableList.copyOf(firstResult));
                            return newExchange;
                        } else {
                            List oldResults = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                            List newResults = newExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                            ImmutableList aggResult = ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.concat(oldResults, newResults));
                            oldExchange.getIn().setBody(aggResult);
                            return oldExchange;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .end()
//                .to("log:bla")
```

Essentially, this route takes an input, sends it to `direct:A` and `direct:B`, expects lists from these two endpoints and concatenates them (the comment in the last line is there for a reason I will explain later).

Now assume that these two endpoints "return" the lists [A] and [B], respectively. If I send the message `M` to `direct:multicaster`, then the aggregator is called once with `oldExchange = null` and `newExchange.in.body=[A]`, then with `oldExchange.in.body=[A]` and `newExchange.out.body=[B]` (as it is supposed to do).

All good up to this point. But the aggregator is called once more with `oldExchange.in.body=[A,B]` and `newExchange.in=M` (`M` is the initial message). This looks similar to an included enrichment pattern.

You can get the expected behaviour by removing the comment in the last line, i.e. simply adding a dummy `to("log:bla")`. With this everthing behaves as expected.

#### Update: Trying (cf. the hint provided by Claus)

```
            .multicast()
            .aggregationStrategy(aggStrategy)
            .to("direct:A", "direct:B")
            .end()
```

and

```
            .multicast(aggStrategy)
            .to("direct:A", "direct:B")
            .end()
```

both result in the same behaviour.

What is happening here - what did I get wrong?

thanks in advance
markus

Comment: You should have aggregationStrategy before to

Comment: Hi Claus, I added two new versions I tried with your hint and still get the same behaviour - there must be something I'm missing here

Comment: What version of camel do you use? Are you sure that the code pasted into the question is the exact code that is running? I can not reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I sondrewe, I'm using 2.11.1; I'll try it with the latest version and if it still fails I will extract the full (minimal) example

Comment: I create a self-contained example that shows the full example (it's a test-setup): https://gist.github.com/frickm/7114961 . There are two important lines to look at: line 91 with the commened-out log-endpoint and line 45 where I weaved in a mock-endpoint to make testing possible. Removing the weaveAddLast() in line 45 it seems to work but renders it impossible to be tested.

Comment: The weaveAddLast statement seems to add that processor to the multicast statement. You can debug and see that the list of processors passed to the MulticastProsessor constructor contains both direct:d1, direct:d2 as well as mock:results. 

To test add the .to(mock:results) to the end of the route.

Comment: that is what I did to make it work (somehow) - but it's ugly to have to pollute my production code with mock-endpoints; thanks markus

Comment: Another thing I realized is that, when you use advices, you should start the context yourself after all the advices have been added: read the bottom part of http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html. But even with this the example still dumps. So I consider this as a bug in the way that advices are not inserted correctly respecting the block-structure of the route.

Comment: @fricke any solution here? i am facing the exact same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the problem, but without success. This is what I did:

**The route:**

```
public class MulticastRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        AggregationStrategy myAggregationStrategy = new MyAggregationStrategy();
        List<String> listA = Lists.newArrayList("A");
        List<String> listB = Lists.newArrayList("B");
        from("direct:multicast").routeId("multicastRoute").multicast(myAggregationStrategy).to("direct:A", "direct:B").end();

        from("direct:A").setBody(constant(listA));
        from("direct:B").setBody(constant(listB));
    }

    class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
        @Override
        public org.apache.camel.Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
            System.out.println("Aggregate called with oldExchange = " + (oldExchange == null ? "null" :
                    oldExchange.getIn().getBody().toString()) + ", newExchange = " +
                    newExchange.getIn().getBody().toString());
            return newExchange;
        }
    }
}
```

Created a simple test just to run the route.

**The test:**

```
public class MulticastRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
  @Test
    public void testMulticastRoute() throws Exception {
        context.addRoutes(new MulticastRoute());
        template.sendBody("direct:multicast", null);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Aggregate called with oldExchange = null, newExchange = [A]
Aggregate called with oldExchange = [A], newExchange = [B]
```

This is what we would expect. Hope this will help you. I can not see any difference in the way I do things, but hopefully you will spot it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 2 things seem to be crucial

- set AggregationStrategy before to (i would set it directly as parameter of multicast)
- end the multicast with "end()"

I think you can see the difference if you look at the return types of each node

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the aggregation strategy is a shared block of code across difference object instances. So the difference kicks in whenever the instance is created.