# Apache Camel Multicast on JMS Topic then Aggregate responses

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

I'm running into a challenging situation where I am trying perform a scatter-gather EIP pattern on an ActiveMQ broker. For my design, I have decided to use a [RouteBuilder](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder.html). The route I want to do is something like this:

```
ActiveMQ:Queue:Test -> Multicast -> ActiveMQ:Topic:Vendors -> Aggregate (Responses received from ActiveMQ:Topic:Vendors) -> ActiveMQ:Queue:Test
```

Essentially I want to be able to send a request XML message to the ActiveMQ Queue "Test" and the request message is multicasted to all Vendors subscribed on the Topic "Vendors" and then collect all the responses (there could be N Vendors, there is no limit here however the completion interval is defined to 10 seconds) then process the responses into 1 XML to send back.

The routing code I have looks like this:

```
from("activemq:Test").setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut).multicast().inOut("activemq:topic:Vendors").aggregationStrategy(new GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy()).end().to("activemq:test").end()
```

The request looks like this:

```
String xml = ...; // Code to create the XML body
Object result = pt.requestBody("activemq:test", xml);
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Playing around with this code I've come across instances where I would get the result of the requestBody I just sent. This is contrary to what I expected to receive.

I've looked at all available resources (camel docs, example code) but I can't figure this issue out. I am still relatively new to camel.

Edit: It seems the problem originates in the request-response portion of my request. When I change the "to" endpoints to a list of JMS queues the aggregation works as expected and I get a proper response back. However, the moment I use a JMS topic I will get a "Reply received for unknown correlationID" warning. Digging a little deeper into the problem I found this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26185840

Looking into the camel code I found, I found why I get that particular issue:

```
if (handler != null) {
    correlation.remove(correlationID);
    handler.onReply(correlationID, message, session);
}
```

This is line 82 of org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyManager. The correlationID is removed from the CorrelationTimeoutMap so the next response that comes in with the same correlationID is not handled. Since I'm dealing with JMS topics, I'm not able to generate a "unique" correlationID.

Would there be a way to aggregate all responses based on a "CorrelationID"? I've already tried using header("CorrelationID")

Comment: So what errors do you get?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage

Comment: It's actually a 3 step process. The first exception I get is a NotSerializableException (Probably caused by my aggregator?). The second is not an exception, but rather a warning in the logs: "Reply received for unknown correlationID [Camel-ID-Jon-PC-1518200327189-0-5]. The message will be ignored" The third is a warning as well: "Timeout occurred after 20000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-Jon-PC-1518200327189-0-2] on destination temp-queue://ID:Jon-PC-56798-1518200327796-1:1:1."

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this question related?

[Apache Camel: multicast with aggregation - AggregationStrategy called too often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511699/apache-camel-multicast-with-aggregation-aggregationstrategy-called-too-often)

I know is not the same issue, but there is a tested example using multicast with an aggregator, maybe you can start using "direct" endpoints instead of JMS with ActiveMQ and then change it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This was somewhat helpful. I tried exactly as they mentioned but when I switched from a JMS queue to a JMS topic the aggregator no longer worked as expected and I got a "Reply received for unknown correlationID" warning. I guess another way to approach the first half of my question is answering "How do I use the multicast or recipient-list EIP for a JMS topic?"

Comment: @jon5477 I guess the problem is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168278/apache-camel-reply-received-for-unknown-correlationid
You are receiving the same JMSCorrelationID.
I also found this interesting question about the Request-Reply Pattern.

Comment: I looked at the link you provided and one particular answer drew my interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26185840 Looking further into this I found the reason for why the pattern I originally posted as my question has a flaw. Diving a little bit deeper into the camel JMS code helped me better understand the problem. It seems I am trying to perform a request with multiple responses but unfortunately Camel only expects a single response per CorrelationID. If this is the case I can't do this on a JMS Topic and have to go with Queues. Unfortunately I still do not have a good solution yet.